# UWP - Can't read serial port COM

Tags: c#, uwp

I need to read a weight of an electronic balance, I can send the command to return my weight, but the balance is not responding. I devel
It is an old model HB TRADE.

This developed for Windows 10, previously had a code made in Visual Fox Pro, but is very old and the customer wants to upgrade.

Apparently I can connect to the balance and send the command to return my weight, but the balance never responds.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var deviceSelector = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("COM5");
            var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(deviceSelector);
            if (devices.Any())
            {
                var deviceId = devices.First().Id;
                serialPort = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceId);

                if (serialPort != null)
                {
                    serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
                    serialPort.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
                    serialPort.DataBits = 8;
                    serialPort.Parity = SerialParity.None;
                    serialPort.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None;

                    dataWriteObject = new DataWriter(serialPort.OutputStream);
                    await WriteAsync(WriteCancellationTokenSource.Token);

                    dataReaderObject = new DataReader(serialPort.InputStream);
                    await ReadAsync(ReadCancellationTokenSource.Token);

                }
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TxtRespuesta.Text = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            serialPort.Dispose();
            serialPort = null;
        }
    }

    private async Task ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        Task<UInt32> loadAsyncTask;

        uint ReadBufferLength = 1024;

        // Don't start any IO if we canceled the task
        lock (ReadCancelLock)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            // Cancellation Token will be used so we can stop the task operation explicitly
            // The completion function should still be called so that we can properly handle a canceled task
            dataReaderObject.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
            loadAsyncTask = dataReaderObject.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength).AsTask(cancellationToken);
        }

        UInt32 bytesRead = await loadAsyncTask;
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            TxtRespuesta.Text += dataReaderObject.ReadString(bytesRead);
        }
        //rootPage.NotifyUser("Read completed - " + bytesRead.ToString() + " bytes were read", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
    }

    private async Task WriteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        Task<UInt32> storeAsyncTask;
        String cadena = "@GI;23;";
        char[] buffer = cadena.ToArray();
        cadena.CopyTo(0, buffer, 0, cadena.Length);
        String InputString = new string(buffer);
        dataWriteObject.WriteString(InputString);

        // Don't start any IO if we canceled the task
        lock (WriteCancelLock)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            storeAsyncTask = dataWriteObject.StoreAsync().AsTask(cancellationToken);
        }

        UInt32 bytesWritten = await storeAsyncTask;
        if (bytesWritten > 0)
        {

        }
        //rootPage.NotifyUser("Write completed - " + bytesWritten.ToString() + " bytes written", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
    }
```

Comment: Have you get some error information? Did you mean your bytesRead return null? We didn't have your device for testing, so maybe more information can let people better help you. Use the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomSerialDeviceAccess) for testing to find it is code issue or device issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, of course, your application must declare that it is doing serial communication in the application manifest:

```
<DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
    <Device Id="vidpid:xxxx xxxx">
      <Function Type="name:serialPort"/>
    </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

Could this be the missing bit?

Comment: You can also add <Device Id="any">

Comment: Yes, the project have enable this capability.